# Let the img element dictate width of container

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the image resolution width dictate the width of the container. The trick is that when a p element gets wider than the image, the whole container stretches. What I want it to do is for the p element to respect the width of the image and never stretch the container width more than the image does. I don't want to set a fixed width. Here's a demo:

```css
#outer, #inner{
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#outer {
  border-color red;
}
#inner { border-color: red; display:inline-block; }
img{max-width:100%;}
.fixed {
  width:300px; /*This is what i'm trying to avoid*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>containers, img, p test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/24yy8hv.jpg" />
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis dui, varius in ligula id, ultricies rutrum lorem. Mauris felis mauris, pretium in leo ut, convallis tincidunt libero. Proin vel ultrices diam, nec rutrum purus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner" class="fixed">
        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/24yy8hv.jpg" />
        <p>
          This is how the first one is supposed to look. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis dui, varius in ligula id, ultricies rutrum lorem. Mauris felis mauris, pretium in leo ut, convallis tincidunt libero. Proin vel ultrices diam, nec rutrum purus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the CSS to inline-block will mean the elements increase with the size of the image.

I added inline-block for just the id img to show you how it can work.

```css
#outer, #inner, #img {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
#outer {
  border-color red;
}
#inner { border-color: red; display:inline-block; }
#img { border-color: blue;display:inline-block;}
img{max-width:100%;}
.fixed {
  width:300px; /*This is what i'm trying to avoid*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>containers, img, p test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">
        <div id="img">
          <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/24yy8hv.jpg" />
        </div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis dui, varius in ligula id, ultricies rutrum lorem. Mauris felis mauris, pretium in leo ut, convallis tincidunt libero. Proin vel ultrices diam, nec rutrum purus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner" class="fixed">
        <div id="img">
          <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/24yy8hv.jpg" />
        </div>
        <p>
          This is how the fist one is supposed to look. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc felis dui, varius in ligula id, ultricies rutrum lorem. Mauris felis mauris, pretium in leo ut, convallis tincidunt libero. Proin vel ultrices diam, nec rutrum purus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope that is what you were after.

Comment: No, it's not, sorry. I want the resolution of the image itself to determine the width of its container. It does do it by default, unless a p element is in the same container as the image. In that case, the wider element of all children will determine the width of the container, but that's not what I want. I want the image to determine that and not the p element, even if it's wider. EDIT: I removed a redundant element from my demo to make it clearer.